# How to skip 'getJSON' error handling if AJAX request is interrupted by the user following a different link

Tags: jquery, json, error-handling

I have in my homepage an AJAX function. If the AJAX method triggers an error, it displays error text on the screen.

```
 $.getJSON(url,
    {},
    function (data) {
        ......
    }
    ).error() {
        ShowError();
    }
);
```

Sometime the user clicks on a link to another page while the function tries to get the data, and then the function stops and displays the error text until the next page is loaded.

How can I handle it so it won't show the error text in this case where the user clicked on a different link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind a '[click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)' event to the **a** tag which sets a global flag. Then only show the error message if the flag is not set.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linkClicked = false;
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
        linkClicked = true;
    });
});
```